# Why jquery is not working inside ajax function ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Why doesn't jquery work within ajax method?

```
<body>

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<p id="demo">Let AJAX change this text.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      $('#demo').html('Hello World');
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
```

now here

```
$('#demo').html('Hello World');
```

it's not working.

but this does

```
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'asas';
```

why ? What could bt the reason. I have tried to change id to class but no luck.

Comment: Did you include jQuery script into your page?

Comment: Its strange that you're using raw XHR despite of including jQuery in your page.

Comment: That code should work if jQuery is there and the Ajax call is successful. What is the error message in your console?

Comment: Does it work outside the ajax? You have not provided much debugging information or any mention of errors

Comment: Whats is the demo element, your not updating the DOM using innerHTML

Comment: @m.nachury that's what `html()` does and the demo element is clearly shown in OP code

Comment: Yeah sorry my double bad

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in jQuery
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Right before the `</body>` tag.

As @31piy mentions in his comment, you can use jQuery's ajax functions like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.get('ajax_info.txt', '', function(response, textStatus) {
        $('#demo').html('Hello World');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```